# MapStruct nested object, create target object only if source element is not null

Tags: java, null, nested, mapstruct

I want to map nested java objects. `Customer.address.houseNumber` to `userDTO.homeDTO.addressDTO.houseNo`.

**Expectation:**  If and only if  `Customer.address.houseNumber`  is not null, then create `homeDTO` object under `userDTO`. Otherwise, do not create any target objects.

**Problem:**  I have used `"NullValueCheckStrategy.ALWAYS"`in the mapper, but *mapstruct* is checking if `address` is not null then it creates `homeDTO`. Inside the `address`, the `houseNumber` is `null`. I would like the null check till the `houseNumber` (leaf/last level object) and then create the target objects.

How can I achieve this?

Here is mapping that I am using.

```
@Mapper( nullValueCheckStrategy = NullValueCheckStrategy.ALWAYS )
public interface Customer2UserMapper {

    @Mapping(source="address.houseNumber", target="homeDTO.addressDTO.houseNo" )
    void mapCustomerHouse(Customer customer, @MappingTarget  UserDTO userDTO)  ;

}
```

The generated code  is in https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1303

Comment: There are some typos (error) in the code that you attached, e.g. `customer.getAddress()=.getHouseNumber()`

Comment: Thank you Andrii. Corrected it.

Answer (score 5):

This is something similar as in [mapstruct/mapstruct#879](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/879). Currently what you are looking for is not possible.

A way to do it would be do have an `@AfterMapping` method that will set it back to `null` if the `address.houseNumber` is `null`

Comment: Thank you Filip.  But @AfterMapping  will  be extra code to check if src is null and then set target to null.  I have 1000 elements to be mapped, for  each element i can not do this check.

Comment: I know that it will be extract code, but currently that is the only way to solve the problem that you have. That is why I linked you to the issue, where you can comment and upvote.

Comment: After almost 2.5 years is there any update on the same? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @vkrishna17 https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1306

Comment: ugly, but setting it back to null in @AfterMapping worked for me.  could probably do something similar with a Decorator too

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using nested mappers.
mapCustomerToHouse mapper will use mapHouseNumberToHouseNo mapper to map houseNumber to homeDTO, since they are not the same type.
The nested mapper will check whether houseNo is null and if so, not instantiate the HomeDTO object:

```
@Mapping(source="address.houseNumber, target="homeDTO" )
void mapCustomerHouse(Customer customer, @MappingTarget  UserDTO userDTO)  ;

@Mapping(source="houseNumber, target="addressDTO.houseNo" )
HomeDTO mapHouseNumberToHouseNo(Integer houseNumber)
```