# Set parent target to null if source is null in MapStruct

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have the following Mappings

```
@Mappings({
        @Mapping(source = "id", target = "id"),
        @Mapping(source = "childId", target = "child.id")
})
Entity objectDtoToEntity(ObjectDTO objectDTO);
```

How could I configure my Mapper or Mappings so when I have childId as null the target Entity.child would be set null not Entity.child.id?

Comment: This is a duplicate: see a better solution on the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46469955/mapstruct-nested-object-create-target-object-only-if-source-element-is-not-null/).

Comment: See [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46469955/mapstruct-nested-object-create-target-object-only-if-source-element-is-not-null/) for a different solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found not a very elegant solution as for me but working solution.

First change interface to abstract class then add  `@AfterMapping`

```
@Mappings({
        @Mapping(source = "id", target = "id"),
        @Mapping(source = "childId", target = "child.id")
})
public abstract Entity objectDtoToEntity(ObjectDTO objectDTO);


@AfterMapping
public Entity doAfterMapping(@MappingTarget Entity entity) {
    if (entity != null && entity.getChild().getId() == null) {
        entity.setChild(null);
    }
    return entity;
}
```

Comment: Currently that is the only way to do that. There is an open issue for this exact problem. Have a look at [#1166](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1166)

Comment: Any updates here to achieve this case in more elegant way? As now it has been more then 2 years since this question was asked.